# csrf token issue with multiple templates

Tags: html, ajax, django, templates, csrf

I've got a template (index.html. It extends base.html) containing a form with a csrf_token which works good. I use JS/Ajax to send data to my view. So no problem with that.

The issue is that if I copy/paste my form to another template (for example : new.html which also extends base.html) I get : CSRF token missing or incorrect error. (HTTP 403 error in console)

Both templates use same JS function. The forms are exactly the same in both templates.

Any suggestion please?

Here the form (same in index.html and new.html) :

```
<form method="post" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
    <a href="#" class="heart pull-right" onclick="return Favorite(this)" data="foobar">
        <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
    </a>
</form>
```

Here the JS/Ajax function :

```
function Favorite(item) {
    song_id = item.getAttribute("data"),
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        url: "/fav/",
        data: {
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
            song_id : song_id
        },
    });
    return false
```

By the way, the form in index.html is in a div. In new.html the form is in a table. Don't know if it helps.

Comment: Show `new.html` just a snippet where you are using the form. Also the `JS` function.

Comment: Do you need more informations?

Comment: First check if the token is being passed or not? In your JS function `alert` or write to `console.log` the value of `$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()` e.g. `alert($('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val());`

Comment: It returns the token value in index.html template. But it returns "undefined" in new.html template

Comment: @NabIlovich so obviously, your selector for csrf is wrong! or the input field isnot there in new.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work (based on django doc and doniyor comments)

```
function getCookie(name) {
var cookieValue = null;
if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
        // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
            break;
        }
    }
}
return cookieValue;
}

function Favorite(item) {
  song_id = item.getAttribute("data-mp3"),
  csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
  $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    datatype: "json",
    url: "/fav/",
    data: {
      song_id : song_id
    },
    headers: {
      'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you dont need `<form>` at all if you are sending the request with ajax.

secondly, you can set the `csrf_token` also in this way:

```
...
data: {
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
    song_id : song_id
},
...
```

which always works for me.

Comment: I removed the form and tried your code with no result :/. I still get a 403 issue.

Comment: @NabIlovich what version of django are you using?

Comment: @NabIlovich just copy this file, save it to separate js file, and import it into your base.html to the top. http://pastebin.com/u7vbfDMK

Comment: Django 1.7 and python 3.4

Comment: If i understand your script, it reads the csrf token from the cookie right? (Im new to developement). I added it but no result.

Comment: @NabIlovich it sets the csrf token in Request Header: ``xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));``