# url patterns for home views or using views accross apps

Tags: python, ajax, django, url

I've been reading about urls, but I can't seem to find a analogue to what I'm trying to do.  I have an app called profile, the views.py in this app queries the database and returns user specific content - I use filters to summarize the db content to whatever user is logged in.  In my "home page" I would like to have a summary of the database across all users.

so the urls used in the profile app looks like this:

```
url(r'^profile/$', 'profile.views.profile', name='profile'),
url(r'^profile/usrDash$', 'profile.views.usrDash')
```

the first one renders the "profile page" and the second is used by an ajax call to send some user specific info which in turn is used to formulate the query.  That's working fine; no issue there.

so what if I wanted to display the same information, use the same query, on the "home page" too?  How do I do that?  Not exactly what I want to do, but If I can this to work I can adapt it later.  I've tried:

```
url(r'^home/usrDash$', 'profile.views.usrDash')
```

but ajax doesn't seem to like it.  there are no error messages it just doesn't POST anything.

I've also tried writing another view in home.views.py, but I can't seem to get the url right.  Since the url pattern for "home page" is:

```
url(r'^$', 'home.views.home', name='home')
```

wouldn't the url for a query at home.views.py be:

```
url(r'^/usrDash$', 'home.views.usrDash')
```

The ajax call in question looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "profile/usrDash",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,
            someVariable: someVariable,                         
           },
          success: function(Data) {                             
            ...
            ...             
          },
          error: function() {
            ...
            }
        });
```

So the ajax call from "home" is a copy of the ajax call used in "profile" with the modification of adding the profile/.  But that doesn't work either.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two apps, one called "profile" and another called "home". If I understand correctly, you would to like make an ajax post request processed by "profile.views.usrDash" to get information for the home page.

So, why not just make the ajax request to '/profile/usrDash'? Why are you associating a different URL pattern with the usrDash view?

The code you provided which attempts to reuse the usrDash view has an incorrect path. It should be **profile.views.usrDash**

Comment: ArbyA, I fixed my typo in path I posted here.  my code had the correct path.  I also added the ajax call.  thanks for your note; any further guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there were two issues with my code.  The first was the way the csrf token was being passed to ajax.  In my profile app this works:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,
```

But it doesn't work in home app.  I don't know why.  It works in one app and not the other.  What did work is:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
```

I found this answer on this post:

[csrf token issue with multiple templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26702551/csrf-token-issue-with-multiple-templates)

The second issue was the url, which was easy to diagnose once the csrf token issue was resolved.  the final url is simply:

```
url(r'^usrDash$', 'profile.views.usrDash')
```

No need for the leading /.

Thanks to ArbyA for taking time to look through my code and thanks to doniyor whose response to the post linked above helped finally get this working.

Regards.